# How to use different From Addresses to send emails from php laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

So i have a SaaS application that enables users add their gmails and then use that added gmail to send emails to collected leads from the app. So that means the from address will change for every user as we want the emails to appear like their been sent from that user's connected gmail.
But gmail keeps overriding when i set the from address to the current tenants connected address and instead picks the one on my env file. This is my mail class:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class CampaignEmails extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $body;
    public $subject;
    public $sender;
    public $sender_name;
    public $email;
    public $name;
    public $company;
    public $position;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($audience, $campaign, $test = false)
    {
        $this->body         = $campaign->body;
        $this->subject      = $campaign->subject;
        $this->sender_email = $campaign->from_email;
        $this->sender_name  = $campaign->from_name;
        $this->email        = $audience->email;

        if ($test) {
            $this->name     = $audience->f_name.' '.$audience->l_name;
        }else{
            $this->name     = $audience->name;
        }
        $this->company      = 'Test Company';
        $this->position     = 'Test Position';
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->sender_email, $this->sender_name)
            ->subject('[TEST] '.$this->subject)
            ->replyTo($this->sender, $this->sender_name) 
            ->view('emails.campaign');
            

    }
}
```

Thank you guys

Comment: That’s probably _spam protection_, they don’t let you send an email pretending to be someone else, than the account you actually used to authenticate against their mail server with. So if you wanted to do this, you would need to ask all your users for not only their email address, but also their login credentials to Google …

Comment: I suggest you look into using an emailing service such as [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) and setting your user's Gmail address as the Reply-To address.

Comment: I can set the reply to email and that is all